# Js сохранить бинарный файл пришедший ссервера

Tags: javascript, binary, blob

Получаю с API бинарный файл (png) в ответе, использую Blob и file-saver(библиотеку)...После сохранения картинка не читается

```
.then((res) => {
    const file = new Blob([res], {type: 'image/png'})
    FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'data-fileName.png')
```

Comment: не читается чем? и как вы пробуете ее "прочитать"?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было указать в запросе responseType: "blob"
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType